# Please help me with proving a subgroup is normal

Tags: abstract-algebra, normal-subgroups

Question:

> Let $G$ be a group and $N = \{g_1h_1g_1^{-1}h_1^{-1} \dots g_nh_ng_n^{-1}h_n^{-1} \mid n \in \Bbb N, g_i, h_i \in G\}$. Show that $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

I have shown that $N$ is a subgroup of $G$, but I can't show that it is normal. The only tool I can think of is the definition, so I pick arbitrary $g_0$ from $G$ and put it and its inverse on both side of an element of $N$, but I can't see why this new thing is in $N$. I tried to write $g_0 = ghg^{-1}h^{-1}$ for some $g, h \in G$ but clearly this does not work in Abelian case. (Perhaps this *will* work in non-Abelian case? We don't need to care about Abelian groups since their subgroups are normal.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach of conjugating an arbitrary element of $N$ is fundamentally sound, but you need to elaborate the argument to rewrite the conjugates of commutators as commutators themselves.

Observe that you can rewrite
$$
\begin{align*}
g_0(g_1h_1g_1^{-1}h_1^{-1})g_0^{-1}
& = 
(g_0g_1g_0^{-1})(g_0h_1g_0^{-1})(g_0g_1^{-1}g_0^{-1})(g_0h_1^{-1}g_0^{-1})\\
& = (g_0g_1g_0^{-1})(g_0h_1g_0^{-1})(g_0g_1g_0^{-1})^{-1}(g_0h_1g_0^{-1})^{-1}
\end{align*}
$$
I leave it to you to argue either the general case, or why this implies the general case.  (Note that a slight variation of this argument shows that $N$ is not just normal but fully characteristic.)

Comment: Oh damn holy crap... Silly me. Thanks for the hint. By the way would you mind help me this concern: I am going to have final soon (next week). However I was too busy this semester and did poorly before in this Abstract Algebra course. I think I managed to grasp all concepts now. But as you can see, I am very unfamiliar with pretty standard tricks like this one, and not adept with using concepts. Are there ways that I can make myself do very well in final? The final is not going to be very hard but I want to do it perfectly.

Comment: @MonkeyKing I don't think there's any shortcut to obtaining a proper grasp of conceptual material.  My only advice is to study with what time you do have, within reason.